# Chart label(legend) not showing in SwiftUi on both axis

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts

I am not able to display the axis label for both the axis for chart in SwiftUi .the chart is showing up but labels of the axis and legend are not showing up. my code for displaying the chart are below.[the result of the code are stated below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKYzL.png)

```
struct ReferData:Identifiable,Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let month:String
    let referCount:Int
    
    init(month:String,referCount:Int) {
        self.month = month
        self.referCount = referCount
    }
}

import Charts
struct ReferDashBoardView: View {
    
    @State var referData:[ReferData] = [
        ReferData(month: "Jan", referCount: 10),
        ReferData(month: "Feb", referCount: 23),
        ReferData(month: "Mar", referCount: 18),
        ReferData(month: "Apr", referCount: 48),
        ReferData(month: "May", referCount: 12),
        ReferData(month: "June", referCount: 38),
        ReferData(month: "July", referCount: 23),
        ReferData(month: "Aug", referCount: 29),
        ReferData(month: "Sept", referCount: 34),
        ReferData(month: "Oct", referCount: 42),
        ReferData(month: "Nov", referCount: 32),
        ReferData(month: "dec", referCount: 45)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading,spacing: 12){
                
                Chart{
                    ForEach(referData,id: \.self) { item in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Month", item.month),
                            y: .value("ReferCount", item.referCount)
                        )
                    }
                }
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(minHeight: 350)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show axis labels you need to use the .chartXAxis() and .chartYAxis() below the Chart{}. Like this:
[image: We can see the result of this Image]

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading,spacing: 12){
                
                Chart{
                    ForEach(referData,id: \.self) { item in
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Month", item.month),
                            y: .value("ReferCount", item.referCount)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.green.gradient)

                     // Show the text inside barChart in black color

                        .annotation(position:.overlay,alignment: .center)
                        {
                            Text("\(item.referCount,format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                        }
                    }

                }
                // Show the XAxis value label in black Color
                .chartXAxis {
                    AxisMarks { value in
                        AxisValueLabel().foregroundStyle(.black)
                    }
                }
                // Show YAxis Value label
                .chartYAxis {
                    AxisMarks { value in
                        AxisValueLabel().foregroundStyle(.black)
                    }
                }  
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,minHeight: 300)
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show axis labels you need to use the .chartXAxisLabel() below the Chart{}. Like this:

```
    var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(alignment:.leading,spacing: 12){
            
            Chart{
                ForEach(referData,id: \.self) { item in
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Month", item.month),
                        y: .value("ReferCount", item.referCount)
                    )
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.orange)
            .chartXAxisLabel("Month", position: .bottom)
            .chartYAxisLabel("ReferCount", position: .trailing)

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(minHeight: 350)
    }
    .padding()
}
```